# How to pass spinner data from one activity to another ?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, spinner

This code is not reading the value from the spinner it's reading only the first value always,

```
btnResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    final String USN = spnConversions.getSelectedItem().toString();
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseResult.class);
        i.putExtra("getData",USN.toString());
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you want to pass a single data or whole spinner at a time ?

Comment: I want to pass just one value one time. It's like if i select 10002 it always pass the first value 10001 always.( i have given these numbers in order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why you are using onClickListener for Spinner ? You should use OnItemSelectedListener() for Spinner see the below example code,

```
public class MySpinnerSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Now register listener using following code,

```
 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MySpinnerSelectedListener());
```

You can pass it using following code,

// Sending Code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseResult.class);
intent.putextra("getData",USN.toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

// Receiving code,

```
String value= getIntent().getStringExtra("getData");
```

Comment: i am using the same thing in my another activity. That is not the problem but whenever i select 10002 from the spinner it's not getting the position value from the spinner. do i need to add any code in first activity.

Comment: Thanks, i made a little changes just i called my btn.onClickListener() from spinner.onItemSelectedListener(), it's working.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuble time.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
int positionitem = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SpinnerExample extends Activity
{
     Spinner sp;
     String text ="";
     Button btnResult;

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                   {
                     this.text = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

                   }
                   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                   {
                            / TODO Auto-generated method stub                  
                   }
          });
          btnResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
          btnResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
          {

                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) 
                  {
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DatabaseResult.class);
                        i.putExtra("getData",this.text);
                        startActivity(i);
                  }
           });
    }
}
```