# Pass DatabaseReference one activity to another using .putExtra() or whatever?

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, spinner

```
public class MoreQP extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_more_qp);


    filterSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showResult();
        }
    });

    resultCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent showresulPage = new Intent(MoreQP.this, ShowQuestion.class);
            showresulPage.putExtra(mDatabase);
            showresulPage.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            MoreQP.this.startActivity(showresulPage);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

public void showResult(){
    resultDisplay.setText(selectedSubject+"\n"+sy+" "+ss+" "+se);
    resultCard.setVisibility(resultCard.VISIBLE);

    //"selectedSubject","sy","ss" etc.. I have taken these values from multiple spinner. 
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Department").child("CSE").child("Year").child(sy).child(ss).child(se).child(whichSemester).child(selectedSubject);


}

}
```

Here is the short-cut version of my code. I want to pass Firebase reference "mDatabase" to my 2nd Activity. I took all those values from multiple spinners. So is there any way to pass this reference to new activity? And how I can receive it on 2nd activity?

Comment: no need to pass the reference, just write the reference in the second activity, if you want to pass anything, then pass the value of the selected spinner

Comment: Are you suggesting to pass all these spinner value to 2nd activity?

Comment: no, I'm just saying if you want to pass anything then you pass the data not a reference. So for example if you have one spinner and you selected `food` in that spinner then you can pass that value to the second activity. (that is all I mean)

Comment: Your idea makes sense. As I said "selectedSubject","sy","ss" these are public string where I save all these spinner values. So can you give me a example how I can pass these values to next activity using putExtra()?

Comment: in your code that is not possible, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928747/how-to-pass-spinner-data-from-one-activity-to-another (to see what I mean by passing values). Those public strings that you are referring to are childs in your database, so you cannot do that. What you can do is what Alex said in the answer and in my first comment

Comment: Thanks Peter, Your reference helped much! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add the `DatabaseReference` object to an Intent in order to use it to another activity, just simply create the same `DatabaseReference` and use it in the second activity. That's it!

Comment: Maybe you haven't understand. "selectedSubject","sy","ss" all these files are dynamic. As I used spinner to set values. So I need this Reference Tree.

Comment: In order to achieve this, don't pass the `DatabaseReference` object to the intent, just pass the value of the selected spinner. Then create in the second activity the `DatabaseReference` based on that value.

Comment: Yes Alex, I would like to add a proper solution. And thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not put Storage / Database Reference in putExtra but you can certainly put string value of path

```
'String storageRef = "group/"+UID+"/"+"profileImage";
 String postUploadRef="User/"+UID;'

Intent mServiceIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, UploadService.class);
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("stream", filePath);
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("stroageRef", storageRef);
        mServiceIntent.putExtra("postUploadRef", postUploadRef);
        startService(mServiceIntent);
```