# Populating a spinner with data obtained from a spinner in a different activity

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, spinner

how do I populate a spinner to depend on spinner data in a different activity?In android studio using java and also with sqlite db.

I already have both spinners but I am struggling to make the second spinner depend on the first spinner data to populate itself.

Comment: [is this your question's answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928747/how-to-pass-spinner-data-from-one-activity-to-another)
you can pass data through intent with putextra.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.